# Laravel Eloquent - How to group conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using the following eloquent statement

```php
Title::where('word', 'lovers')
    ->orWhere('word', 'lover')
    ->where('domain', $resultFromFirstKeyword->domain)
    ->get();
```

Which I can see through the SQL logger produces the following SQL

```sql
SELECT * FROM `title` 
WHERE `word` = 'lovers' 
OR `word` = 'lover' 
AND `domain` = 'www.texasbirdlovers.com'
```

However the SQL that I would like to produce is

```sql
SELECT * FROM `title` 
WHERE (`word` = 'lovers' OR `word` = 'lover') 
AND `domain` = 'www.texasbirdlovers.com'
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work:

```
Title::whereIn('word', ['lovers', 'lover'])
    ->where('domain', $resultFromFirstKeyword->domain)
    ->get();
```

If, however, you want to combine them exactly like you said, try this:

```
Title::where(function($query) {
        $query->where('word', 'lovers')
            ->orWhere('word', 'lover');
    })
    ->where('domain', $resultFromFirstKeyword->domain)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```php
Title::where(function($query) {
    return $query
        ->where('word', 'lover')
        ->orWhere('word', 'lovers');
})
->where('domain', $resultFromFirstKeyword->domain)
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `group` your query in a `where` clause

```
Title::where(function($q){
         $q->where('word', 'lovers')->orWhere('word', 'lover');
 })->where('domain', $resultFromFirstKeyword->domain)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```sql
Title::where('domain', $resultFromFirstKeyword->domain)
    ->where(function($query) {
        return $query
            ->where('word', '=', 'lovers')
            ->orWhere('word', '=', 'word');
    })->get();
```